# How do I get Evolution to delete e-mail on Gmail account?

Tags: evolution, gmail

How do I make Evolution delete mail in my Gmail account using POP3?

Answer (score 4):

If you're wanting to remove the mail as you check it from the Pop3 GMAIL server, make sure you have this set in  Evolutions Preferences ( **Edit > Preferences > Account Settings** )

[image: Account Settings]

You should also do as ichtyandr noted and change the setting in GMail's settings.

> it's a Gmail setting, in Gmail/Settings/Forwarding and POP/IMAP on POP question number two "2. When messages are accessed with POP " choose option to delete the Gmail copy

[image: Gmail Settings]

Answer (score 1):

its a gmail setting, in Gmail/Settings/Forwarding and POP/IMAP on POP question number two "2. When messages are accessed with POP " choose option to delete the Gmail copy

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you can't, from Evolution. You're using Pop3, which doesn't sync the mailboxes, it just downloads. If you were using IMAP, it would sync.

As the other two answers said, you can set that up in gmail, but than those messages are inaccessible in gmail (depending on your settings there).

What I suggest you do is delete the pop3 account in Evolution and make a new account that uses IMAP, not really the answer you're looking for, but most likely a better solution in the long run.